# 'vmethodptr' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, pointers, methods, virtual

After decompiling, I have the following error within Visual Studio and I do not understand why.

> Error CS0103
>   The name '__vmethodptr' does not exist in the current context   RollCallConsole02   D:\VS Projects\RollCallConsole02\RunRollCall.cs 194 Active

It comes from this part of the code which is exporting data to a report file, so that it can be printed.

[Here you can find a screenshot of Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kErhW.jpg)

and below is the text version of the code.
Any help would be appreciated and if you have questions, please feel free to ask.

```
public void Export(LocalReport report)
{
  string str1 = "<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat><PageWidth>8.27in</PageWidth><PageHeight>11.7in</PageHeight><MarginTop>0.15in</MarginTop><MarginLeft>0.35in</MarginLeft><MarginRight>0.15in</MarginRight><MarginBottom>0.15in</MarginBottom></DeviceInfo>";
  if (RunRollCall.LandscapeLayout == 1)
    str1 = "<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat><PageWidth>11.7in</PageWidth><PageHeight>8.27in</PageHeight><MarginTop>0.15in</MarginTop><MarginLeft>0.35in</MarginLeft><MarginRight>0.15in</MarginRight><MarginBottom>0.15in</MarginBottom></DeviceInfo>";
  Warning[] warningArray = (Warning[]) null;
  this.m_streams = (IList<Stream>) new List<Stream>();
  LocalReport localReport = report;
  string str2 = "Image";
  string str3 = str1;
  RunRollCall runRollCall = this;
        // ISSUE: virtual method pointer
        CreateStreamCallback createStreamCallback = null;new CreateStreamCallback((object) runRollCall, __vmethodptr(runRollCall, CreateStream));
  ref Warning[] local = ref warningArray;
  localReport.Render(str2, str3, createStreamCallback, out local);
  IEnumerator<Stream> enumerator = null;
  try
  {
    enumerator = this.m_streams.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
      enumerator.Current.Position = 0L;
  }
  finally
  {
    enumerator?.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: what the error is saying is that you may have declared that variable somehow but it does not exist in memory at that point of the code running